# I want to generate regular expression for the session token ct=KWG3-Q49R-1FAX-YO56 in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to generate regular expression for the session token ct=KWG3-Q49R-1FAX-YO56(It changes dynamically) in JMeter

Comment: What is your question and what have you tried already?

Comment: The session token passes to all other screens in URL(for Security) after login, so i need to pass it to other calls in JMeter. For this I tried "ct":="(.+?)", but its saying csrf_error.jsp

Comment: Please, specify your exact Session Token Expression.

Comment: add more details to your question. tell us which request you sent. where do you get this session token. what you have already tried.!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to locate the Session Token parameter which is being posted to the Server. It may resides on Request URL, Request Body, or Request Header.

Then, you need to find out the Session Token which gets retrieved from the Server. It may be on any of the previous requests and may retrieved through Response Body, or Response Header.

Now, add the Regular Expression Extractor Post Processor in the request in which Session Token is found. If the original Session Token Expression is as;

```
ct=KWG3-Q49R-1FAX-YO56
```

Then try this Regex:

```
ct=(.*)
```

**Note:** Also add a Debug Sampler in your Testplan/ThreadGroup in order to verify your Regex.